# How to format date string so new Date(string) returns consistent results across browsers?

Tags: javascript, date, cross-browser

How can I format a date string to be recognized as absolute, meaning new Date(string) should return a date object without timezone offset?

I always knew dates in JavaScript where funny, but this is eh... ridiculous?
I hope I am missing something.

FIREFOX:

```
new Date("2015-01-01") -> Jan 1  - OK
new Date("1/1/2015") -> Dec 31  - THAT HURT!
new Date("2015-01-01T00:00:00Z") -> Jan 1  - OK
new Date("January 1, 2015") -> Dec 31 - THAT HURT!
new Date("January 1, 2015 00:00:00") -> Dec 31 - THAT HURT!
new Date(2015, 0, 1) -> Dec 31 - THAT HURT!
new Date(2015, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0) -> Dec 31  - THAT HURT!
new Date(2015, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0) -> Jan 1  - YOU'RE KIDDING ?
new Date("2015/01/01") -> Dec 31  - THAT HURT!
```

CHROME

```
new Date("2015-01-01") -> Jan 1 - OK
new Date("1/1/2015") -> Jan 1 - OK
new Date("2015-01-01T00:00:00Z") -> Jan 1 - OK
new Date("January 1, 2015") -> Jan 1 - OK
new Date("January 1, 2015 00:00:00") -> Jan 1 - OK
new Date(2015, 0, 1) -> Jan 1 - OK
new Date(2015, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0) -> Jan 1 - OK
new Date(2015, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0) -> Jan 1 - OK
new Date("2015/01/01") -> Jan 1 - OK
```

IE

```
new Date("2015-01-01") -> NaN   - THAT HURT!
new Date("1/1/2015") -> Jan 1 - OK
new Date("2015-01-01T00:00:00Z")-> NaN   - THAT HURT!
new Date("January 1, 2015") -> Jan 1  -  OK
new Date(2015, 0, 1) -> Jan 1 - OK
new Date(2015, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0) -> Jan 1  - OK
new Date(2015, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0) -> Jan 1 - OK
new Date("2015/01/01") -> Jan 1 - OK
```

I understand Firefox is compensating for timezone offset in some cases, and I understand IE is wacko. But how can I get a new Date(whatever) consistent across browsers?

As an added bonus if someone can someone explain this behavior, I will be less frustrated, as it turned into a major gotcha for me.

Thank you!

EDIT: Cleaned up output to make inconsistent behavior more clear.
EDIT: Added suggested string format "2015/01/01" - does not work in FF (in my timezone :-/ )

Comment: There is volumes of information on this already available as well as date specifications. What you are asking for can all be found doing some simple web searching. Dates are complicated. Start with [MDN Date Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: If I understand what you mean you want to replace the builtin `Date` object with a custom object so you can override the date parser and the `toString()` method. I suspect the language allows to do so (no idea whether such custom object would be still compliant with the ECMAScript spec) but it can't be a good idea and, honestly, I don't think you really want that. Can't you just use a wrapper with a syntax you like more and a different name, so you don't break everything else?

Comment: @charlietfl: I had hoped so, but have found nothing consistent yet. Also in this forum, there are answers accepted that simply does not work across browsers :-(

Comment: @Álvaro: no, I'm looking for a consistent format of [string] which returns the same date across major browsers when calling new Date([string])

Answer (score 1):

This behavior has been an issue for quite a while and nobody seems to have a clear answer as to why the developers opted for these types of options.  Some "rules of thumb" to follow:

- Stick to "YYYY/MM/DD" for your date strings whenever possible. It's universally supported and unambiguous. With this format, all times are local.
- Avoid using hyphenated dates ("YYYY-MM-DD") unless you know what you're doing. Only newer browsers support them.
- So long as you specify four digits years, date strings at least have a unique parse across all browsers. Some browsers may return an error, but you won't get inconsistent behavior.
- Chrome tends to be more accepting than other browsers. If a date format parses in Chrome, you shouldn't assume that it parses anywhere else.

*The best suggestion I can recommend other than a plug in is to format your input string for the Date function into something you know will be consistent across browsers.  You've done the research, so this should be easy.  Once you get used to doing this for a while, it will become second nature.*

I did find this a while back.  I like the functionality, as it gives me the "choice" of allowing UTC or not: **[HERE](https://github.com/jllodra/dygraphs/tree/UTC/strftime)**

There is also **[DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/)**

Comment: "format your input string for the Date function into something you know will be consistent across browsers" - that's exactly what I am trying to find out. I added your suggested "YYYY/MM/DD" format to the questions, does not work in FF

Comment: Hadn't seen that in the past.  Must be something new ... for my purposes, that means using one of the plugins (like DateJS) becomes much more important.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, but seems crazy that a mundane task like creating a date from a string would require a plugin. Let's wait and see if someone has some insight here.

Comment: I agree ... this is one of those time when a single browser would be awesome!

Answer (score -1):

My option for cross browser compatibility for date would be `Date.parse(<<My Date String>>)` This will return datetime in milliseconds, Then you can format it in any way you want.

I have tried this only in IE8 and Chrome though.

Comment: This has exactly the same behaviour as the mentioned `Date` constructor